# Is there an achievement for getting the basketball in the hoop?

Tags: achievements, overwatch

In the warm up area, you are able to hit around a couple of basketballs. I constantly try to get the basketballs in the hoop, but I end up having to start the game before I make any real progress.

Is there an achievement or anything game related to getting the ball in the hoop?

[image]

Comment: Not sure why a downvote. I think this is a legitimate question.

Comment: I feel this this should be down voted just for playing as McCree ;)

Comment: I doubt they will create an achievement for this. This will have a negative gameplay impact - players may try to fight over the basketball so they can get the achievement. They may also be late to start the match because they are too busy trying to get the achievement.

Comment: @bmarkham I downvoted because "Is there an achievement for <completely random action>" is not a good question IMO.  There are 100 other random actions people do before the round starts that could be asked as equally-bad questions _(eg. "Is there an achievement for knocking all the books off the shelves?  For destroying all the arcade machines?  For playing the Futurama theme song?")_

Comment: I downvoted because there is a complete lack of research effort shown in the question. Funny how many users claim to downvote my questions due to lack of research effort but the OP in this question couldn't even bother to look at the achievements himself.

Comment: @Retrosaur - I simply thought that there would have been something you could unlock by getting the basketball in the hoop. I wasn't aware of any achievement list in-game, because I did try to research the answer to this in-game.

Comment: @JoshSpoors Don't hate the playa hate the game :D

Comment: @Retrosaur: World of Warcraft, Blizzard's slightly more popular game, has several achievements that are not listed until they are earned. Simply looking at the list of achievements is not necessary sufficient.

Comment: @Ellesedil Except this isn't World of Warcraft, it's still Overwatch.

Comment: @Retrosaur: Yes. You miss my point. The game developer has a track record of adding secret achievements to games. Knowing this, is there a secret achievement? This thought process results in this question we're all commenting on. It *could* result in a better question. But, my point is that there's more to this question then just bringing up the list of achievements in the game.

Comment: @Retrosaur, ells saying the developer has a history of adding in things like this. Being that you havnt played any of Blizzards other games before, you would be completely unaware, but this is 100% something they would do.

Comment: This could be platform-dependent. On Xbox, the achievements are all set when the game comes out and new ones are not added unless there is DLC. You can easily check a list of all the achievements online. For now, I'm also downvoting due to lack of research. Also because I'm annoyed with all the Overwatch questions that completely ignore the fact it is also on consoles.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### There are no achievements for getting the basketball into the hoop.

Gameplay-wise, however, is an entirely different manner. When the ball lands in the hoop, an airhorn sounds along with a shower of confetti in your ship.
But besides being able to be used for entertainment, basketballs can be used for even greater sources of entertainments by adding traps to them.

Not only can Symmetra's sentries be placed on a basketball, allowing you to knock it into the air, and hopefully get a few kills as it flies through the air,

[image]

Junkrat's [Steel Trap and Concussion Mines can also be attached for some hilarious shenanigans](https://gfycat.com/MiniatureFragrantBear):

Comment: Please note that [Gfycat](https://gfycat.com) will shut down on Sept. 1, 2023. This affects some of the media you included in your post since it/they were uploaded to Gfycat. I recommend that you edit your post and reupload the Gfycat media through SE Imgur to avoid losing them. You might need to edit the media to make it ≤ 2 MiB, which is the maximum file size allowed by SE Imgur. See [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16826/4797) for more info.

Answer (score 59):

Other than a rightly-earned feeling of self-satisfaction, there are no achievements or game-related consequences to sinking a basketball, yet<sup>1</sup>.

You can [watch this player sink a ball](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ry5lND2TdBk) at around the 20 second mark.

<sub><sup>1</sup> The key word being *yet*. Blizzard have snuck in Easter egg achievements with content updates in the past, so don't put it past them to do it again.</sub>

Comment: Interestingly enough, when you put the ball inside the bin, a message is sent to Blizzard servers (Wireshark), I supsect they are tracking how many people is able to put that ball in the bin to decide if that is worth (and how much is worth) as achievement. Another guess is that they wanted to put that as achivement, but none of Blizzard employes were able to do that task XD

Comment: @DarioOO, thats actually pretty interesting. Sounds like it could simply be novelty data analytics, but do you have a source?

Comment: @DarioOO Possibly trying to get data to see if it is worth adding more time wasting activities during match start-up? Which I for one would be quite pleased with! I hate sitting round for 60 seconds watching Junkrat put traps and charges outside the front door!

Comment: This answer should be updated now that the hoop shows confetti on a successful basket.

Answer (score 9):

With the most recent update to the game, sinking a basket now yields an air horn and some celebratory confetti:

Still no achievement, but at least it's acknowledged now :)

Comment: Video link is broken